# Origen de la expresión "tiempo de Maricastaña"

Tags: expresiones, historia

Se usa a veces la expresión "eso pasó en tiempos de Maricastaña" o "eso es del tiempo de Maricastaña" para expresar que algo pertenece [a tiempos muy antiguos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zir6Ipf#CaT2iJP). Sin embargo, resulta que en tiempos de Mariscastaña ya se usaba la expresión:

> *Marzoco: Pues ya me voy. Vuestras cien monedas agora, Dios lo dijo.
>
>   Lozana: Andá, que ya no es el tempo de Maricastaña.*
>
> Francisco Delicado, "La Lozana Andaluza", 1528 (España).

Esta es el caso más antiguo que encuentro en el CORDE. La palabra *Maricastaña* hoy día no se recoge como tal en el DLE, pero sí lo estuvo en tiempos de Mari... bueno, ya paro. El diccionario de la RAE de 1884 lo define como:

> Personaje proverbial, símbolo de antigüedad muy remota.

Definición que se mantuvo inalterada hasta 1992. Lo que me gustaría saber es:

- ¿Existe alguna versión anterior de esta expresión? ¿O realmente se originó en el siglo XVI?
- ¿Cómo se originó la expresión? Me cuesta trabajo pensar que Maricastaña (o "Mari Castaña" como lo he visto también escrito) sea un nombre inventado. He visto que existió una tal Ysabel de Castaña:

  > *Sereno: [...] Dezidme con qujén fue casado este Conde don Pedro de Villandrando.
  >
  >   Alcaide: Su muger se llamó doña Ysabel de Castaña, que fue muy gentil dama e criada de la Cathólica Rreyna dona Ysabel, pero nunca ovo hijos en ella nj ella parió e le venció de días, la qual asimismo vos y yo la vimos muchas vezes.*
  >
  > Gonzalo Fernández de Oviedo, "Batallas y quinquagenas", 1535-c1552 (España).

  Y también aparece el nombre en un texto de 1467, como parte de un séquito de nueve doncellas de la por entonces princesa Isabel. ¿Tendrá algo que ver con la expresión? Lo veo poco probable, pero no encuentro en el CORDE ningún otro texto que haga mención a otra Castaña.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alfred López, en su blog *[Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/quien-fue-la-maricastanas-del-famoso-dicho/)*, indica que la Mari Castaña del dicho fue un personaje real del siglo XIV que encabezó una revuelta contra la Iglesia en Lugo. Tal como menciona en su artículo, la *[España sagrada](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k92783r.image.f149.pagination)* de Manuel Risco recoge la existencia de esta mujer, haciendo referencia al pergamino del archivo episcopal en que se recoge su participación en tal revuelta y la satisfacción que pagó por ella en 1386, casi siglo y medio antes de la aparición de *La lozana andaluza*.

Parece bastante probable que, en efecto, Mari Castaña se hiciera popular y, aun cuando su vida y hechos han sido olvidados por la mayoría de nosotros, haya quedado memoria de su existencia en el famoso dicho.

Answer (score 0):

De [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_Casta%C3%B1a):

María Castaña, Maricastaña o María Castiñeira fue una mujer española del siglo XIV de la que se sabe en realidad muy poco, más allá de lo que se recoge en un documento del Archivo Episcopal de Lugo citado en la España sagrada[<sup>1</sup>](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k92783r.image.f149.pagination)​ y en el Episcopologio Lucense.[<sup>2</sup>](http://www.abc.es/archivo/20140916/abci-quien-maricastana-aquellos-remotos-201409051422.html).​

> El 18 de junio de 1386 María Castaña, mujer de Martín Cego, Gonzalo Cego y Alfonso Cego, confiesan haber hecho muchas injurias a la Iglesia de Lugo, y haber matado a Francisco Fernández, mayordomo del Obispo. Para satisfacción de estos delitos, hicieron donación a la Catedral de todas las heredades que tenían en el coto de Cereixa y se obligaron a pagar mil maravedíes de la moneda usual.

En la época de Cervantes ya se había convertido en una referencia temporal ambigua para referirse a un pasado muy lejano, equivalente a "los tiempos de Matusalén".

> ... en tiempos de Maricastaña, cuando hablaban las calabazas"[<sup>3</sup>](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_Casta%C3%B1a#cite_note-3)​